# Angular2: Mongooose update not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to update mongo db using mongoose. I am not getting any errors but the update is not happening. I have tried everything possible.

```
  exports.update_a_keyValue = function(req, res) {
    console.log("templatecontroller: update_a_template - templateID:", 
    req.params._id, req.body);
    Template.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body._id}, req.body, {new: false}, 
    function(err, keyvalue) {
    if (err)
       res.send(err);
       res.json(keyvalue);
   });
 };
```

i am getting this in the express window. No errors. In the network side i see 204 and 304 errors.

```
templatecontroller: update_a_template - templateID: 
  5a1c22ab8af22e408c9bd0f4 
{ _
id: '5a1c22ab8af22e408c9bd0f4',
 key: 'testingthisagain',
__v: 0,
  values: [ { value: 'tesddfdfdf' }, { value: 'testingthisagain1' } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

Set {new: true}, to return the updated document, if set to false it return the document before the update.

Comment: Even with {new:true} it is not working. I tried dropping the DB and try again. Create is working and get is working but edit is not. I tried using postman to put data. The return value i am getting is null.  I even tried findbyIdandupdate. It is showing the same behaviour. I am not sure what else i can try. The value is going into the findbyIdandupdate method but the data is not getting update

Comment: I am not sure about this but try putting curly braces for your if block to separate the code. As I read your code, I'd think `res.send(err)` and `res.json(keyvalue)` are under the same `if(err)`. Other than that, I'd love to check it out if you have a github repo for this.